MUI DataGrid sortComparator function signature in typescript
I am using MUI DataGrid ("@mui/x-data-grid"). I am looking to custom sort a column based on other column's values.
const columns: GridColDef<Location>[] = [
  {
    field: "siteNo",
    headerName: "Site No.",
    width: 100
  },
  {
    field: "totalArea",
    headerName: "Total Area (sqm)",
    width: 150
  },
  {
    field: "totalAreaSqFt",
    headerName: "Total Area (sqft)",
    width: 150,
    sortComparator: numComparator,
    valueGetter: (_value: GridValueFormatter, row: Location) => `${Helper.formatNumberWithCommas(Helper.convertSqmToSqft(row.totalArea))}`,
  },
]

const numComparator = (_v1: number, _v2: number, param1: GridCellParams, param2: GridCellParams) => {
  console.log(param1) // has properties of api, field, id, rowNode, value
  
  const v1: number = param1.api.getRow(param1["id"])["totalArea"]
  const v2: number = param2.api.getRow(param2["id"])["totalArea"]
  return v1 - v2
  
}

However, GridCellParams do not have signature to provide api, field, id, rowNode, value as the properties. Though sorting is working fine on dev mode, when I try to build, I get these errors:
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"api"' can't be used to index type 'GridCellParams<any, unknown, unknown, GridTreeNode>'

Property 'api' does not exist on type 'GridCellParams<any, unknown, unknown, GridTreeNode>'

Types of parameters 'param1' and 'cellParams1' are incompatible.

Type 'GridSortCellParams<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'GridCellParams<any, unknown, unknown, GridTreeNode>': row, colDef, cellMode, hasFocus, tabIndex


I am not sure if GridCellParams is the right type of parameter in numComparator function signature. Is there any other type, which matches the properties of api, field, id, rowNode, value? Or with GridCellParams, how can I make it work?
